# Mark highest documents with true

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with two columns:
name and version.

I want to add a boolean in an extra column. So if the highest version then true, otherwise false.

```
import pandas as pd
 
data = [['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['a', 2], ['a', 2], ['b', 4]]
 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['name', 'version'])
 
df
```

is it best to use groupby for this?
I have tried smth. like this but I do not know how to add extra column with bolean.

```
df.groupby(['name']).max()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare maximal values per groups created by [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with `max` for generate new column/ Series filled by maxinmal values, so possible compare by original column:

```
df['bool_col'] = df['version'] == df.groupby('name')['version'].transform('max')
print(df)
  name  version  bool_col
0    a        1     False
1    b        2     False
2    a        2      True
3    a        2      True
4    b        4      True
```

**Detail**:

```
print(df.groupby('name')['version'].transform('max'))
0    2
1    4
2    2
3    2
4    4
Name: version, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign your column directly:

```
df['bool_col'] = df['version'] == max(df['version'])
```

Output:

```
  name  version  bool_col
0    a        1     False
1    b        2     False
2    a        2     False
3    a        2     False
4    b        4      True
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: It should also mark the thow rows with name "a" and version "2" as True.

Comment: oh I didn't get that from your question... @jezrael's solution is the way to go then!